# Change Angular mock value

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an unit test that look like this:

```
describe("myDirective Test",function(){
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        module(function($provide) {
          $provide.constant('Config', {"showmenu":true});
        });
    });

    it('should add showmenu attribute',inject(function($compile,$rootScope){
        var element = $compile('<div my-directive></div>')($rootScope);
        expect(element.attr('showmenu')).not.toBe(undefined);
    }));

    it('should NOT add showmenu attribute',inject(function($compile,$rootScope){
        var element = $compile('<div my-directive></div>')($rootScope);
        expect(element.attr('showmenu')).toBe(undefined);
    }));
});
```

This is my directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$compile','Config', function($compile,Config){
    return {
        scope: true, 
        link: function(scope, element) {
            if(Config.showmenu){
                element.attr('showmenu', "{'height':menuheight,'alwaysVisible':true}"); 
                element.removeAttr('my-directive'); 
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I change the `showmenu` value, so that it is `false` in the `should NOT add showmenu attribute` test?

Comment: Can you share the directive template where you use `showmenu`?

Comment: @Chandermani I have updated my question with my directive example. So, how can it be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inject Config to your test, and change it there:

```
it('should NOT add showmenu attribute',inject(function($compile,$rootScope, Config){
    Config.showmenu = false;
    var element = $compile('<div my-directive></div>')($rootScope);
    expect(element.attr('showmenu')).toBe(undefined);
}));
```

Not sure if your real code is like that, but you have a extra space here:

```
 .directive('myDirective '
```